# Запрос permission java android

Tags: java, android, permissions

Не получается получить разрешение на использование интернета на телефоне android.
Пытался сделать это на android 6.0 В дальнейшем вставил проверку наличия расширения:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) permText.setText("done");
        if (permissionCheck== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) permText.setText("failed");
```

В дальнейшем вычитал что в android 6.0 требуется отдельный запрос и простое прописывание в манифесте не поможет. Тогда изменил targetSDK и minSDK на 15 (android 4.0.3 если не ошибаюсь). По прежнему выдает отсутствие разрешения. Вот мой манифест, вдруг не правильно прописал. Помогите пожалуйста получить разрешения. Не понимаю почему не работает.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.nikita.simpleclient">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Вы показали код проверки наличия разрешений, но не покзали где их запрашиваете. Вы их запрашиваете?

Comment: обьявите permission перед application

Comment: Пермишены выше тега Application напишите

Answer (score 1):

В блоке если разрешение не предоставлено, у вас это `if (permissionCheck== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)` можно программно запросить разрешение, необходимо для версии android 6+

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                    1);
```

Ссылка на документацию - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Более полный код

```
//Проверка версии SDK устройства
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                //динамическое получение прав на INTERNET
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission is granted");

                    //делаете что-то с интернетом

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                    //запрашиваем разрешение
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
                }
            } else {
                //делаете что-то с интернетом;
            }
```

Ну в манифесте permission должно стоять перед application.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, указать строку в AndroidManifest.xml недостаточно. Это было бы слишком просто :) Нужно также написать методы в Java-классе для проверки, было ли выдано нужное разрешение, и если нет, запросить его у пользователя, а затем обработать ответ.
Вот так выглядит проверка и запрос на разрешение (в данном случае на звонки, но можно заменить на другое разрешение):

```
/**
 * проверка наличия разрешения на звонки
 */
private boolean isCallPermissionGranted() {
    int permissionResult = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, CALL_PHONE_PERMISSION);
    return permissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

/**
 * запросить разрешение на звонки
 */
private void requestCallPermission() {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {CALL_PHONE_PERMISSION};
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Максимально подробно об этом можно прочесть в [статье про использование возможностей Андроид](https://beauty-of-java.site/android-development/ispolzovanie-vstroennyh-vozmozhnostej-android/) (звонки, смс и т.д.), там есть про выдачу разрешений.